# How to find and replace a string with PowerShell - issue with Eastern European characters

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script to find and replace xml tags containing Eastern European characters and change them to English.

My source file is encoded in UTF-8.

My code:

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("file.xml").Replace("<Číslo_zboží>","<Code>")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("file.xml", $content)
```

While I can successfully find and replace tags with standard English characters, those containing Eastern European characters are ignored by PowerShell. Many thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`[System.IO.File]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) class's methods default to (BOM-less) UTF-8, so assuming that `file.xml` is UTF-8-encoded (whether with BOM or not), reading and writing that file should work as expected, but note that *writing* will result in *no* BOM.

**I suspect the problem is that your *source file*, despite being UTF-8-encoded, *lacks a BOM***, which Windows PowerShell (unfortunately) requires in order to recognize UTF-8 encoding.

In the absence of a BOM, Windows PowerShell interprets your source file as "ANSI"-encoded, which is the single-byte, extended-ASCII encoding implied by your system's legacy system locale.
So even if your script's actual encoding is UTF-8, **the absence of a BOM means that Windows PowerShell will *misinterpret the non-ASCII characters in the script*, so that string operations based on *string literals defined in the script*  will not work as expected**.

**To be safe, always create UTF-8-encoded PowerShell scripts *with a BOM*.**

Note that the upcoming cross-platform PowerShell *Core* [will likely switch to (BOM-less) UTF-8 as the default](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/issues/71#issuecomment-306614751), but it will continue to recognize BOMs, so saving UTF-8 scripts *with* a BOM should be a future-proof approach.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I have now changed my code to (Get-Content -path "C:\file.xml").replace('<Číslo_zboží>', '<Code>') | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path "C:\file.xml" to keep the BOM and it works like a charm!

Comment: @OKOndrej: I'm glad to hear it; my pleasure. Note that `Get-Content` also defaults to "ANSI" encoding in case the file has no BOM.